# How to crop polygonal shape(showed in below image) in an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, crop

This is the image I am working on?
I want to crop the black part from the image.

[image: enter image description]

Answer (score 0):

Try poly2mask function:

```
BW = poly2mask(x, y, m, n)
```